# No int variables allowed in Python string replacement_field?

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

I am attempting to use `str.format()` for report headers (i.e., columns) with variable widths, but I can't seem to do it using an `int` variable:

```
hlist =['h1','h2','h3','h4']
width = 7

for i in range(len(hlist)):
    # print(hlist[i].center(width), end='  ')       # this works
    print('{:^width}'.format(hlist[i]), end='  ')   # this doesn't
print()

for i in range(len(hlist)):
    # print('------'.center(width), end='  ')       # this works
    print('{:-<width}'.format('-'), end='  ')       # this doesn't
print()
```

Running this code gives me:

```
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Using any `int` literal in place of `width` works fine.  I researched [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and I thought I was getting close with the `format_spec` arg, but it looks like it only supports non-integer formats.  I tried `int()` as well, but no luck.

I'm happy with the solution that works using `byte.center()` but I was looking for a way to make use of the newer syntax for more flexibility.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the width as a variable to the format function, and let it know that you want a variable named `width`, not a literal string. Since braces can be nested, do this:

```
hlist =['h1','h2','h3','h4']
width = 7

for i in range(len(hlist)):
    print('{:^{width}}'.format(hlist[i], width=width), end='  ')
print()

for i in range(len(hlist)):
    print('{:-<{width}}'.format('-', width=width), end='  ')
print()
```

Comment: This is good, thank you.  I'm brand new at this, but can you tell me what happened to the previous answer to this question?  It seems to have been removed.  I thought questions just got voted up, not removed...?

Comment: Not sure actually. I am guessing that the owner deleted it. I don't think it was too terrible, even if it wasn't the canonical answer, so I doubt that a moderator removed it.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the user did that; your answer was more to my point.  I did vote up the answer, however I'm too new for my upvotes to show publicly :-\   Thanks again...

Comment: That's OK. Can you select the answer once the question is closed?

Comment: Yes, it seems I can.  I receive this message after I vote an answer up : Thanks for the feedback!  Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... I was able to select it after all.